# Signin-oidc page direct access error with corelation - how to redirect?

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid-connect

With seting up asp.net core with `AddOpenIdConnect` it creates by defualt `/signin-oidc` page which works fine when accessed from opeind provider.
User is logged in and everything works fine.

Though user can still try to access `mypage.com/signin-oidc` directly and get as a result `Correlation failed` failed error.

How can I properly handle access to this page so that it still works for openid flow, but doesn't produce error (redirects) when accessed directly? (tried overwrite Route with HttpGet already)

**EDIT**
To elaborate, going to `/signin-oidc` is giving 500 status with base startup like

```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "test";
                options.ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret");
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://test.net";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.Scope.Add("openid");

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                    {

                        var claims = new List<Claim>();
                       claims.Add(new Claim("jwt", ctx.SecurityToken.ToString()));
                        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);                           
                        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                    }
                };
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://test.net";
                options.Audience = "authorization.sample.api";
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            });

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Test API"
            });
        });
    }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot")),
            RequestPath = "/dist"
        });


        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Host.Host.ToLower() != "localhost")
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            await next.Invoke();
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=LandingPage}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute("Spa", "{*url}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });



        var swaggerJsonEndpoint = "api-docs/{0}/swagger.json";

        app.UseSwagger(so => so.RouteTemplate = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, swaggerJsonEndpoint, "{documentName}"));

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/" + string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, swaggerJsonEndpoint, "v1"), "Test API v1");
            c.OAuthClientId("admin.implicit");
        });

    }
```

```

Comment: Can you share your Startup.cs code? Are you running multiple nodes?

Comment: edited. but I think nothing interesting or new is there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happened to me previously as well, and I think this is just an artefact of how the OpenId system works in ASP.NET Core. I believe there was a Github issue for this but I can't seem to find it ATM. I'll have a look around and post it if I can find it.

In any case, I was able to fix this by adding an event to the the OpenId options events that just redirects to "Home" on any remote failures:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
    // Your events here
    OnRemoteFailure = ctx => {
        ctx.HandleResponse();
        ctx.Response.Redirect("Home");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
```

See if that works for you...

**EDIT:** This is the issue and comment with suggested fix for your reference https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/720#issuecomment-368484827

Comment: Gah, thank you so much! We were running into this when the user clicked the link from a Word document. Typing the same URL in the browser worked fine.

Comment: This is a beautiful fix.  Straight and to the point.  Still works on .net6 in 2022