# How to navigate to proper unauthorized page when AD authentication is FAILED

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an .Net core web app with Azure AD Authentication. In appsettings.json, I have mentioned "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc" while setting up the azure AD.

IN Azure portal, I have added reply url as "https://localhost:44350/signin-oidc"

This is authenticating fine. But when user authentication is failed, it is navigating to /signin-oidc by showing exception:

OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'interaction_required', error_description: 'AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application

Instead I need to show proper Microsoft page that says user is not authenticated. something like below.
[AD Auth Failed Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXd8a.png)

Can someone please assist me on this ?

Comment: I guess the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474201/signin-oidc-page-direct-access-error-with-corelation-how-to-redirect

Comment: Hi Roar.  Thanks for your response.But this navigates to HOME controller. Problem is my web app still done have proper landing page for now. It will work when it is navigated from other website with specific query string values.    This is why i just want to show the user that sign in failed and other details. I have attached the screenshot of my requirement.

Comment: Thank you Roar. We have followed the approach you have mentioned. That works.